# Do I need to ask the phone user for permissions to write and read the local database? (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

1. Before `creating` a local `SQLite database` on the user's phone. Should `permission` be requested for: `WriteExternalStorage, ReadExternalStorage`?
2. Before `saving` the data to the local `SQLite database` on the user's phone. Should `permission` be requested for: `WriteExternalStorage, ReadExternalStorage`?

On some phones, users get an error when launching the app

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionException: StorageRead permission was not granted: Denied
```

This error occurs on `Android 11`. But when I try to reproduce the error on the `Android 11 emulator`. I'm not getting any error. I'm confused. I don't understand why everything works on the emulator, even if all permissions in the phone settings for the application are disabled.

Or I don't need to ask for `permission` from the phone user: `WriteExternalStorage, ReadExternalStorage`. And it will just be enough to add in the `Assemblyinfo.cs` file of the Android project ?

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. there is a standard example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/

Comment: Do you know which phones are having these problems? Could you tell me the brand and model in detail?

Comment: 1. Redmi Note 8 Pro – Android 9 , 2. Galaxy A21s – Android 11, 3. POCO X3 Pro – Android 11